Mediapipe get persistent id of tracked hands between frames
I am using mediapipe to get the landmarks of multiple hands of a live video. I now want to know how each hand (more than 2) have moved in between the frames. For this I need to remember which hand was which in each result callback.
I am using this solution: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/hand_landmarker
I could of course just track the hands manually by looking at the average position of each hand and hoping they are not swapped between frames. But as the mediapipe model in itself does the tracking, I would like to use it's tracking as it is probably more robust than my simple tracking and it is also less hacky to do two different trackings for one task.
I could also imagine that the hands are always in the same order of the multi_hand_landmarks object, but I could not find evidence for this and this leaves a problem when one hand disappears. I cannot find a id per hand which is persistent across frames in the multi_hand_landmarks object.

what makes you think that mediapipe did any tracking? it might just do detection and pose estimation, without any tracking required.

On the provided link, it states that it does tracking: "Since running the palm detection model is time consuming, when in video or live stream running mode, Hand Landmarker uses the bounding box defined by the hand landmarks model in one frame to localize the region of hands for subsequent frames. Hand Landmarker only re-triggers the palm detection model if the hand landmarks model no longer identifies the presence of hands or fails to track the hands within the frame. This reduces the number of times Hand Landmarker tiggers the palm detection model."

great! all of that will happen in code, not in the model, so you might be able to find it in their source code. IDK if they expose this through the API. if not, you can always just edit the package's code, or copy the code into your own project and modify it.
